# VBScript position of XML node to use as index to another node

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, wsh

I have the following XML:

```
adapt.xml:    
 <Adapters>
   <Adapter>
    <IPAddresses>
      <IPAddress>1.1.1.1</IPAddress>
      <IPAddress>2.2.2.2</IPAddress>
      <IPAddress>3.3.3.3</IPAddress>
    </IPAddresses>
    <IPSubnets>
      <IPSubnet>255.0.0.0</IPSubnet>
      <IPSubnet>255.255.0.0</IPSubnet>
      <IPSubnet>255.255.255.0</IPSubnet>
    </IPSubnets>
  </Adapter>
</Adapters>
```

I am trying to align the selected IPAddress with the corresponding IPSubnet like this:

```
Set adaptersDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
adaptersDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
adaptersDoc.Async = False
adaptersDoc.Load("adapt.xml")

For Each ipNode In adaptersDoc.selectNodes("//IPAddresses/IPAddress")
    WScript.Echo "ipNode", ipNode.Text
    WScript.Echo "subnet", ipNode.selectSingleNode("//IPSubnets/IPSubnet[ count(preceding-sibling::IPAddress)+1 ]").Text
Next
```

My current output is this:

```
ipNode 1.1.1.1
subnet 255.0.0.0
ipNode 2.2.2.2
subnet 255.0.0.0
ipNode 3.3.3.3
subnet 255.0.0.0
```

My desired output is this:

```
ipNode 1.1.1.1
subnet 255.0.0.0
ipNode 2.2.2.2
subnet 255.255.0.0
ipNode 3.3.3.3
subnet 255.255.255.0
```

I am trying to get the xpath to select the same postion of the IPSubnet element with relation to the IPAddress position.

Obviously, count(preceding-sibling::IPAddress) isn't doing what i think it should.

It seems like this should be working because the node context knows it's own previous and following siblings, but when I try to use it as an index to IPSubnet[x], it doesn't give me the desired results.

I need to do this in the XPath string, not by changing the program to do stuff like iterating nodes and use counters or lengths of the nodes and childNodes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I think your assumption isn't correct. By doing `//IPSubnets/IPSubnet` the node context changed to `<IPSubnet>`. At this context, calling `count(preceding-sibling::IPAddress)` always yield `0` because `<IPSubnet>` in your XML never have any preceding sibling `<IPAddress>`. That's why you got `//IPSubnets/IPSubnet[1]` -which value is `255.255.255.0`- in every iteration.

The closest I can get is something like this :

```
For Each ipNode In adaptersDoc.SelectNodes("//IPAddresses/IPAddress")
    WScript.Echo "ipNode", ipNode.Text
    xpath = "//IPSubnets/IPSubnet[position() = count(//IPAddresses/IPAddress[.='" & ipNode.Text & "']/preceding-sibling::IPAddress)+1]"
    WScript.Echo "subnet", ipNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).Text
Next
```

Output :

```
ipNode        1.1.1.1
subnet        255.0.0.0
ipNode        2.2.2.2
subnet        255.255.0.0
ipNode        3.3.3.3
subnet        255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you har07.
I see the error of my ways. It wasn't clicking that the context node shifted until you pointed it out, and I threw it into C# with a real debugger to see the node.

I was trying to avoid making code changes because the same technique is used in other instances within the data set.

So since I have to make a change, i'm going a slightly different route with:

```
ipXPath="//IPAddresses/IPAddress"
subnetXPath="//IPSubnets/IPSubnet[ $position()$ ]"
i=0
For Each ipNode In adaptersDoc.selectNodes(ipXPath)
    i=i+1
    WScript.Echo "ipNode", ipNode.Text
    WScript.Echo "subnet", ipNode.selectSingleNode( Replace(subnetXPath,"$position()$",CStr(i)) ).Text
Next
```

It does what I need to do. Thanks for the assist.